# In R script the code runs, but as soon as I knitr it throws an error, and I cannot imagine what could be the issue

Tags: r

So, when I run it in R script it does work, but when I knitr it in R markdown it gives an

```
error:
'by ' must specify a uniquely valid column...
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
winners <- merge(x = golden_globes, y=oscars, by = "nominee", all = TRUE) 
winners <-  winners %>% group_by(nominee) %>% 
          transmute(win = Globes + Oscars, film, year_film) %>% 
          distinct() %>% 
          arrange(desc(win))
```

I am sure that the column nominee belongs to both tables, because I checked it with View function. On the R markdown file there is almost all the script that is on Rmd file. So, I don't understand what's the issue.

Comment: All objects and dataframes used in the original script must also be available for the knitting process. Is this code inside or outside a snippet?

Comment: @mhm I put all the script inside the chunks, the only thing I didn't include was install.packages. Also there are separations between these chunks, if that changes anything? For some of them I put echo =FALSE, but for some no.

Comment: Is the column `nominee` the same datatype in both dataframes? Check with `str(df$nominee)`

Comment: The commands to load the data and those that create the "by" columns, or modify them, must also be in the file. The keywords are "almost all". You have to have "all"!